# Image not carrying over from CSS

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm attempting to set up an anchor tag to scroll from bottom to top of the page, and the functionality works fine - but the arrow icon I want to display isn't showing up from the linked CSS.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="anchorScroll" style=""></a>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Anchor to move to top*/

.anchorScroll {
    content:url(https://visualpharm.com/assets/98/Upward%20Arrow-595b40b85ba036ed117dbd06.svg/200x200);
    background: #8994a5;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

And here is a JS Fiddle [link.](https://jsfiddle.net/24665qkd/) Thanks in advance for any help that anyone can offer.

Comment: check the url... remove the last `/200x200`

Comment: The `content:` property has to be used with ::before or ::after, you can't apply it directly to an element.

Comment: Seems like your image url not correct

Comment: Thanks @gp that sorted it perfectly. Also thanks to delinear and KMS

Answer (score 1):

You have change this:

```
content:url(https://visualpharm.com/assets/98/Upward%20Arrow-595b40b85ba036ed117dbd06.svg/200x200);
```

to this:

```
background:url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/98/Upward%20Arrow-595b40b85ba036ed117dbd06.svg');
```

Changed "content" to "background", put the link to quotations, and removed 200x200.

Full code is here:

```
.anchorScroll {
        background:#8994a5 url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/98/Upward%20Arrow-595b40b85ba036ed117dbd06.svg');
        color: #fff;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

Comment: You also put the background-color and background-image together, which was a problem aswell.

Comment: An above solution worked how I wanted, but I ended up using yours as I liked how the end result looked better. Thank you @Aslan Shemilov

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: Hey Maharkus, where you see problem when I put the background-color and background-image together? Can you clarify that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **200x200** from content url link see below

```css
.anchorScroll {
    content:url(https://visualpharm.com/assets/98/Upward%20Arrow-595b40b85ba036ed117dbd06.svg);
    background: #8994a5;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anchorScroll" style=""></a>
```